# Python: Embed 'Start_date' & 'End_date' as variables under SQL within Python Script

Tags: python, variables

I am using Python to connect to Amazon Redshift to pull data, the following part is to execute the SQL part. ('engine' and related libraries are already defined)

```
try_data = pd.read_sql_query(text(try_sql), engine)

try_data.head(3)
```

It works fine if 'start_date' and 'end_date' is hard coded under SQL query like:

```
try_sql = """
select * from users where created_at >= '2019-07-01' and created_at < '2021-07-01' limit 10
;
"""
```

But fails if I try to define `start_date` and `end_date` as variables and then put it into the query:

```
start_date = '2019-07-01'
end_date = '2021-07-01'
```

```
try_sql = """
select * from users where created_at >= '", start_date , "' and created_at < '", end_date , "' limit 10
;
"""
```

With the error message: **(psycopg2.errors.InvalidDatetimeFormat) invalid input syntax for type date: "", start_date , ""**

How can I change it? Thanks!

Comment: `try_sql = f"""
select * from users where created_at >= '{start_date}' and created_at < '{end_date}' limit 10
;
"""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now the `try_sql` **returns**

```
select * from users where created_at >= '", start_date , "' and
created_at < '", end_date , "' limit 10;
```

using **format-string** you can do something like this

```
try_sql = f"""
select * from users where created_at >= '{start_date}' and created_at < '{end_date}' limit 10;
"""
```

and it would **return**

```
select * from users where created_at >= '2019-07-01' and created_at < '2021-07-01' limit 10;
```